# Ошибка expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++

код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct ch {
      int chislo;
      int st_2;
      int st_3;
      }; 
vector <ch> ch_v;

int main() {
  int n, i, dv = 0, tr = 0;
  cout << "Skolko budet chisel?";
  cin >> n;
  int a[n];
  cout << "Vvedite chisla";
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
  sort (a, a + n);    
  ch_v.push_back(ch);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ch_v[i].chislo = a[i];
    cout << ch_v[i].chislo << " ";
    while (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
      a[i] /= 2;
      dv++;
    }
    ch_v[i].st_2 = dv;  
    cout << ch_v[i].st_2 << " ";
    dv = 0;  
    while (a[i] % 3 == 0) {
      a[i] /= 3;
      tr++;
    }
    ch_v[i].st_3 = tr;
    cout << ch_v[i].st_3 << " ";
    tr = 0;       
  }
  getch();
  return (0);
}
```

**`ch_v.push_back(ch);`** вот в этом месте выдает указанную ошибку. Никак не могу понять, что не так

З.Ы. помидорами прошу не кидаться, я еще новичок

Comment: ch - имя структуры, а не сам объект. Вы пытаетесь его засунуть в вектор. В вектор нужно класть объекты.

Comment: Как тогда можно создать вектор из структур?

Comment: Вы его уже создали в строке `vector <ch> ch_v;`.

Comment: структура - пользовательский тип данных, как и любую переменную объект структуры нужно объявить.

ch some_struct;

Comment: @akisha, всегда описывайте *по русски*, что Вы **хотите** сделать, не надейтесь, что найдется много любителей изучать чужой код (с ошибками и без комментариев) и пытаться понять, а что именно должна делать программа.

Comment: А в какой строке ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь в вектор вставить тип данных структура. Не само значение структуры, а тип.

Вместо `ch_v.push_back(ch);`

нужно писать что то вида

ch dd;
dd.chislo = ...; // здесь нужно подставить нужные числа.
dd.st_2 = ...;
dd.st_3 = ..;

ch_v.push_back(dd);

Но логика этого push_back в данном месте от меня ускользает. Поэтому не могу сказать, что именно там нужно вписывать.

Код конечно нужно хорошо отформатировать. Это не питон, тут отступами не поможешь.

И хорошо было бы само условие приложить.

Comment: Задача еще совсем не доделана, к сожалению
Как надо форматировать код?
Вот текст задачи: 
Даны N положительных целых чисел, которые не делятся ни на какие простые числа, кроме 2 и 3. Требуется выкинуть минимально возможное количество чисел так, чтобы из любых двух оставшихся одно делилось на другое.

Comment: чуточку переформатировал код.

> чтобы из любых двух оставшихся 

судя по этому условию, у Вас должно остаться два числа.

Comment: Нет, должна остаться последовательность, чтобы взяв любые два числа из нее, одно будет делиться на другое, и при том эта последовательность должна быть наибольшей из возможных